# When you choose to engage an enemy, do they engage you too?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

If I'm engaging an enemy in the staging area that has an action that happens when they engage me, does that action occur when I engage them instead?

For example, if I engage [Hummerhorns](http://www.lotrlcg.com/Card/Focus/1075) before my Threat hits 40 and they engage me, do i still have to deal 5 damage to one of my heroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.  From page 16 of the rules

> Whether an enemy is engaged through an engagement check, through a
>   card effect, or through a player’s choice, the end result is the same,
>   with the enemy and the player engaging one another. In all cases, the
>   player is considered to have engaged the enemy and the enemy is
>   considered to have engaged the player.